# Zimbra 8.8.15 CLI account status update issue

Tags: zimbra

This is Zimbra Admin specific question -

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue:
On account lockout, a

```
zmprov ma XXXX zimbraAccountStatus active
zmprov ga XXXX | grep zimbraAccountStatus
```

yields as expected `zimbraAccountStatus: active`

however as soon as a login is attempted the system still reports `account lockout`

Does anyone know why this is the case and what is the cause - to fix?

The system: Release 8.8.15.GA.4179.UBUNTU20.64 UBUNTU20_64 FOSS edition, Patch 8.8.15_P45.

I have tried checking the logs to see if there is any trace of an error, but to no avail.

It does seem that if the status is changed through the zimbraAdmin web interface the effect is immediate.